# How to implement bidirectional conversion with From trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

Suppose I have the following type:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo(pub i32); // public
```

Since it's a tuple with a public member, any conversions from/to `i32` can simply be made using the `0` member:

```
let foo = Foo::default();

let num: i32 = foo.0; // Foo to i32
let goo = Foo(123);   // i32 to Foo
```

Now I want to make the `0` member non-public, implementing [From trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html):

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo(i32); // non-public

impl From<i32> for Foo {
    fn from(n: i32) -> Foo {
        Foo(n)
    }
}
```

But the conversion fails from `i32`  to `Foo`:

```
let foo = ay::Foo::default();
let num: i32 = foo.into();    // error!
let goo = ay::Foo::from(123); // okay
```

What's the correct way to implement this bidirectional conversion? Rust playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3797660e24ba314419cc9b44bc38427c).

Comment: You have to implement both directions independently as they have nothing to do with one another, most infaillible conversions are injective rather than bijective e.g. str -> path or i32 -> i64 but not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the other direction (`impl From<Foo> for i32`) manually:

```
mod x {
    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct Foo(i32);

    impl From<i32> for Foo {
        fn from(n: i32) -> Foo {
            Foo(n)
        }
    }

    impl From<Foo> for i32 {
        fn from(foo: Foo) -> i32 {
            foo.0
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = x::Foo::default();
    let _num: i32 = foo.into(); // okay
    let _goo = x::Foo::from(123); // also okay
}
```

You can test this in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=362c4c22bf9cde795873e6f4ac1ceea7)